# iOS: Is it possible to revert a version in tesflight

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I accidentally submitted an app with a version number that is way over the existing version to TestFlight. i.e existing version is 1.1.1(5) and mistakenly I submitted 3.1.1(1.) Now when I try to submit an app to TestFlight with previous version with a build number slightly over than the previous (i.e 1.1.1(6)) I am not permitted. Is it possible to revert/delete the app with accidental build version.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to reset your version via website @madu